# How to prove the following inequality: $(1-\max_{1\leq i \leq k}\mathbb{P}(A_i))^k\leq \prod_i \mathbb{P}(A_i)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, inequality

> How to prove the following inequality: Let $\varepsilon>0$, and $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_k)\leq \varepsilon$, 
>   $$(1-\max_{1\leq i \leq k}\mathbb{P}(A_i))^k\leq \prod_i \mathbb{P}(A_i)$$

I try to prove it by induction. For $k=1$, it is obvious that $1-\mathbb{P}(A_i)\leq \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ holds if fix $\varepsilon=1/2$. But how to prove it for general $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality seems to be false. Let $k=2, P(A_1)=P(A_2)=\frac 1  4$ with $A_1 \cap A_2=\emptyset$. The inequality becomes $(1-\frac 1  4)^{2} \leq \frac 1 {16}$ which is false.

Comment: I think $\sum P(A_k)=1$ is implied.

Comment: @JMP Even if you have sum instead of product in RHS the inequality is still false.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(A_i)=\frac1k$.

The LHS is now $(1-\frac1k)^k\to e^{-1}$ and the RHS is $\frac1k^k$.

The RHS is $\lt$ the LHS for all $\varepsilon$, so your conjecture is false.